# Camera Perspective Not Working

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera, settings

The Problem: The camera viewport is not working when I switch to camera view using "Numpad 0". The camera outline guides do not show as they usually do, and the Camera Perspective viewport does not render in any setting except for the viewport shading "Rendered" setting of which the guides do not appear.

[image: This is the "User Perspective" viewport]

[image: This is the "Camera Perspective" with "Viewport Shader" set to "Solid"]

What I was doing when the issue developed: I was renaming the cameras and I may have caused a mismatch with the camera and it's label. I attempted to use illegal characters in the name, for example "C-Camera". I may have accidently hit a random key while attempting to label the cameras.

I have checked:

- The camera is not clipping
- The camera is the active camera for the scene
- I have deleted all cameras and tried to re-add the cameras.
- The Resolution X is 1920 px and the Resolution Y is 1080 px.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this and reset the camera guides?

Comment: Have you tried pressing Home button? Do you have this list checked? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Comment: Can you  provide the file without unnecessary meshes (characters, pants, etc…)?

Comment: Yes, the home button fixed it! Thank you very much. Do you know what might have caused it?

Comment: This can happen if you forget that you are in camera perspective, maybe you were in camera and you tried to move with shift (which keeps camera perspective but it moves your view), then you probably changed back to 3d view and your camera view was stuck outside of the camera perspective... maybe, or something else(maybe you scrolled with your mouse and zoomed too much..., just remember that home button will always restart your view to active